# Ongoing error closing council motions in Polkadot JS (No execution details available for this proposal)

Tags: polkadot-js, error

**Ongoing problem with closing council motions related to treasury proposals. Here is what we have tried so far.**

(1) At first, running an August 2022 version of the substrate kitchen sink node, the **close button was simply greyed out**.

(2) We tried upgrading the WASM to a December 2022 version. Closing a motion was possible then but got an error of **wrong proposal length**.

(3) We tried disconnecting the Polkadot JS, clearing browser data and reconnecting the Polkadot JS. The close button was now unavailable due to an error of **No execution details available for this proposal**.

(4) We tried another WASM update to include all changes to the Substrate kitchen sink node as of January 2nd (no custom code) (code is here: https://github.com/SparticleConcepts/Geode-Substrate/tree/Geode-Beta). But the same error persists: **No execution details available for this proposal**.

(5) We tried connecting the Polkadot JS to various nodes on our network, and we tried connecting it to Polkadot and then back to our network (because sometimes that helps with other issues), no change, same error.

We CAN force treasury proposal approvals via a sudo call BUT the motion for that proposal in the council will remain open. The **No execution details** error is the same for all proposals, regardless of which runtime version they were made on, and whether or not they were forced-approved or not.

There was a similar issue reported a week ago at GitHub but it was considered unrepeatable: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/8638

This issue is on our test chain so our next move would be to restart our entire test chain from zero but that is obviously less than ideal and may not solve the problem as it seems to be a JS problem rather than a runtime problem. We are using the standard Polkadot JS apps seen here: https://polkadot.js.org/apps/#/explorer

**Any other ideas?**

Answer (score 1):

found this (https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/7790) suggesting that there are one or more offending props from before the runtime upgrade that cannot be decoded and that, like xmas lights, if there is one bad one, the whole list will act badly. … removed old proposals by disapproving them via extrinsics. Now everything works well in the council.